# Problema ao customizar a barra de pesquisa

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, estou tendo problemas em conseguir fixar a barra de pesquisa no centro da navbar, tendo em vista que toda alteração na css não muda em nada.

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>

          <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
          <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Main CSS -->
          <link href="src/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Start Navigation bar -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <form class="form-inline mr-auto">
                    <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- End Navigation bar -->

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

#search .form-control {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Obrigado pela paciência.

Comment: Está tendo fazer sua barra de pesquisar ser responsiva? Isso talvez ajude: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_searchbar.asp

Comment: @WandersonRodrigo Oi, na verdade estou tentando fixar a barra de pesquisa no centro da navbar, tendo em vista que atualmente ela está no canto esquerdo, desculpe se eu não fui claro na pergunta.

Comment: Olá @Nithogg, tudo bem?

Já tentou atribuir a class="fixed-top"  no seu navbar? Acredito que possa solucionar seu problema.

Comment: Estes exemplos aqui podem ajudar:[link](https://www.codeply.com/go/kTGlK9Axdk)

Comment: Com ajuda de muitos aqui percebi vários erros no código, revisarei tudo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara seu código tem alguns errinhos.

Primeiro vc tem no CSS uma classe pro `ID #search`, mas no HTML nenhum elemento tem esse `ID`.

Vc pode utilizar as classes nativas do Bootstrap para alinhar do jeito que vc quer. Primeiro com `w-100` vc deixa o form com `100%` da largura, depois com `m-auto` vc deixa o `input` centralizado.

**OBS:** Vc usou algumas classes como `mr-auto` de maneira equivocada ao meu ver, isso tb atrapalha. Além disso estão faltando classes importantes na sua `navbar`, tente seguir a documentação! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

***Execute em "Página toda" para ver como ficou, pois vc está usando a classe `navbar-expand-md` na `navbar`, isso não deixa ela aparecer nas tela pequenas***

```html
<html>

    <head>

          <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
          <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Main CSS -->
          <link href="src/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<style>

.navbar {
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

#search .form-control {
    width: 200px;
}
</style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Start Navigation bar -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <form class="form-inline w-100" id="search">
                    <input class="form-control m-auto" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- End Navigation bar -->

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Desculpe essas bobeiras, estou há muito tempo sem utilizar bootstrap e fiquei meio perdido agora que voltei. Vou revisar as classes ausentes. 
Obrigado pela ajuda didática! ;D

Comment: @Nithogg tranquilo framework eh para isso, já vem com as classes embutidas para serem usadas mesmo rss. A parte chata eh que temos que seguir a documentação. Inclusive o próprio bootstrap 4 já tem todas as classes de Flex nem precisa escrever na mão como o amigo da outra resposta sugeriu... Procure nos utilits d bs4 por Flex que vc vai ver ;)

Comment: O importante não eh corrigir a qq custo, o importante eh entender onde se está errando, Pq, e como corrigir

Answer (score 2):

Segue amigo

```
<html>

<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="src/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Start Navigation bar -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="search">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- End Navigation bar -->

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
     background-color: #3f3f3f;
        }

#search {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center
}
```